# Is there a scripting tool for Mac?

Tags: bash, ksh, zsh, sh, osx-leopard

Is there a tool for Mac OS like Windows VBScript?

I want to write some script which generates folders automatically and copy & paste files according to input.

Answer (score 3):

It's called [AppleScript...](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptX/AppleScriptX.html)

**BUT**

python is also another option that comes packed with OSX that has filesystem tools, and probably most popularly, OSX's terminal is bash, so most bash shell scripts will also work with OSX.

Comment: OSX also includes versions of python and perl

Answer (score 1):

There is Automator, a tool to create automated tasks.  It's quite packed with useful stuff out of the box and easy and fun to use.

Answer (score 0):

Apple-script is probably what you're looking for. Some applications have extensive support for Apple-script, whether made by Apple or not. Apple-script can also run shell scripts with the:

```
do shell script ""
```

command. In the Apple-script Editor there are templates for folder manipulation. Apple-scripts can also be saved as Applications. I use this for launching command-line programs (Ex: Andriod SDK)

You can also write a shell script and rename it *.command so it can be double-clicked to execute